# Ansible: Unexpected failure during module execution "find() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Tags: ansible

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
>   traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: find() takes exactly 2
>   arguments (3 given) fatal: [smuc8562]: FAILED! => {"failed": true,
>   "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

we get this error while trying to run an Ansible playbook with win_package module.

```
 - name: Install JDK - {{ jdk_exe }}
    win_package:
      path: '{{ jdk_exe }}'
      arguments: /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"
      product_id: "{{ jdk_product_id }}"
      state: present
```

Ansible master: SUSE Linux x64 running with Python 2.6.9
Windows target: Windows Server 2012 R2

Other instances of win_package work fine.

We tried raw command, and replacing win_package with win_command, but the issue persists.

Comment: Have you tried put all the `arguments` in quotes? -  `arguments: '/s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"'`

Comment: Yes, we get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the Python to 2.7.14 will solve the problem.